# React Native - Funtion passed as a paramater is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am new to React Native and I am trying to create a simple app with tab navigation to fetch NBA data. I created a Team page with 2 buttons to fetch East or West conference team data. I tried to pass all the params from App.js to Team.js. It was meant to be fetching the data from the API when button is clicked.

However, an error occured when i tried to press the button in Team (the two buttons in Category component)
Error: Category.js:13:70 TypeError: undefined is not a function, js engine: hermes) ... a function (confOncClick) that was used in the Category.js (A component in Team page) is undefined

Error screenshot: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JPSph.png)

App.js

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, Alert} from 'react-native';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import {v4 as uuid} from 'uuid';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';

import Team from './pages/Team';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './pages/Home';

import axios from 'axios';

const App = () => {
  const [teamData, setTeamData] = useState([]);
  const [confIndex, setConfIndex] = useState();

  function SettingsScreen() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <Text>Settings!</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }

  const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

  const confOnClick = async text => {
    console.log(text);
    if (text === 'East') {
      setConfIndex(0);
    } else {
      setConfIndex(1);
    }
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com/teams',
      params: {conference: text},
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': /.../,
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-nba-v1.p.rapidapi.com',
      },
    };
    await axios
      .request(options)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.response);
        console.log(typeof response.data.response);
        setTeamData(response.data.response);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Header />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
          <Tab.Screen
            name="Team"
            component={Team}
            options={{confOnClick: confOnClick, teamData: teamData}}
          />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Team.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Alert} from 'react-native';
import ListItem from '../components/ListItem';
import Category from '../components/Category';

function Team({confOnClick, teamData}) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Category confOnClick={confOnClick} />
      <FlatList
        data={teamData}
        renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem item={item} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
export default Team;
```

Category.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Alert} from 'react-native';
import ListItem from '../components/ListItem';
import Category from '../components/Category';

function Team({confOnClick, teamData}) {
  return (
    <View>
      <Category confOnClick={confOnClick} />
      <FlatList
        data={teamData}
        renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem item={item} />}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
export default Team;
```

the confOnClick passed to Category seems to be undefined but I am not sure what is the issue. Could be because of the way I pass from app.js?

```
<Tab.Screen
            name="Team"
            component={Team}
            options={{confOnClick: confOnClick, teamData: teamData}}
          />
```

hope I made it clear and please let me know if I can provide more info

I have tried passing the params in different ways in Tab.Screen navigator with initialParams, params, options and also change the component to children but somehow i didn't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use initialParams in Tab.Screen like

```
<Tab.Screen
        name="Team"
        component={Team}
        initialParams={{confOnClick: confOnClick, teamData: teamData}}
      />
```

Team.js

```
function Team({route}) {
    const {confOnClick, teamData} = route.params;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @phuocantd , thank you the issue seems to be fixed and the button is fetching data but there is an warning:
```
Console Warning of Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. Check:

Team>params.confOnClick(Function)

This can break usage such as persisiting and restoring state......
```

should i just use a logbox to ingore it or is there any way to fix? Thanks for the help!

Comment: because it is function, i think you should not pass function

Comment: @LauRicky You can use it to pass function: 
<Tab.Screen
        name="Team"
        component={()=><Team  confOnClick={confOnClick}  teamData={teamData}/>}
      />